# Clusters with innegal number of nodes in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, server, hardware

Schema :

I have two DCs:

DC1 has 3 servers, each with 1 Tera as storage.
we have NetworkToplogyStrategy and GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Let`s supose i have an incoming data of 1T ( over a period of time, not all at once ) with replication of 3. That supposes to fullfill my storage in the 3 servers from DC1.

My question :

Is it possible ( recommended or not ) in the other DC2 ( with replication factor of 3 also ) to deploy 6 machines with 0.5 T as storage space to be able to sustain the 1T flow? ( also i might have more local connections in DC2 )

NOTE: I ask you this, because is possible in future in different datacenters to have different infrastructure and hardware capabilities so i need to know if in my problem DC1 and DC2 can work with that hardware schema.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends what the second database is about. Sometimes, it is to store a replica in a different location, so you have a global replication of 3 (2 in the first cluster and 1 in the second).

Comment: I will try to test that today to check on. Normally it should work also my case scenario over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible ( recommended or not ) in the other DC2 ( with replication factor of 3 also ) to deploy 6 machines with 0.5 T as storage space to be able to sustain the 1T flow?

In theory yes it is possible.

Now in practice, depending on how data are really balanced, sometimes you don't have a perfect distribution of 1/6 of data on each node so you may face issues with disk space. If is very true with virtual nodes, although it's better in Cassandra 3.x because the token allocation algorithm has been improved.

Also, if you're using SizeTieredCompactionStrategy, you should reserve some disk free space for compaction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question is really "Can I have datacenters with different topologies?", and the answer is yes - you could very easily have a DC with RF=N=3 , and a second DC with nodes that are half the size and RF=3, N=6, and another datacenter with tiny nodes and RF=3, N=12.